# add_foreign_key does not generate a new column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, foreign-keys

I create a new migration for table `orders` and expect a foreign key `user_id` for table Users. The relation between `Order:User=N:1`. The migration file is:

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.datetime :begin
      t.integer :plan
      t.boolean :activiated
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :orders, :users
  end
end
```

After done rake db:migration, I logs in rails console:

```
2.1.10 :010 >   Order.column_names
 => ["id", "begin", "plan", "activiated", "created_at", "updated_at"] 
2.1.10 :011 > User.column_names
 => ["id", "name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest", ...]
```

but I did not find user_id column.

I followed [3.6 Foreign Keys](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys), which says the foreigh key should be there. Is there something I am missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it says in the guides

```
add_foreign_key :articles, :authors
```

> This adds a new foreign key to the author_id column of the articles
>   table

it adds a foreign key constraint on a column, and the column must already be in the table. So you must include that before in your migration.

```
create_table :orders do |t|
  t.datetime :begin
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :plan
  t.boolean :activiated
  t.timestamps null: false
end
add_foreign_key :orders, :users
```

Comment: My poor english understanding.. So, should I make any modification(e.g., re-generation the model), if I add user_id column in the migration file and do migration?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, but you can rollback a migration with `rake db:rollback` and then run again with `rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run `rake db:rollback` and then add `t.integer :user_id` in the earlier migration file and save the file.

And then run `rake db:migrate`. Hope this will help to solve your problem in the given case.